# Django user authorization

Tags: python, django, authorization

I'm interested in implementing a web application utilizing Python and Django and I'm in the process of researching capabilities to ensure it's feasible within my allotted timeframe. However, I'm having a difficult time finding any documentation/examples/etc on one core piece of functionality I require. Specifically:

If I have a heirarchy of users such as:
manager
employee

With the rules:

- An employee reports to one manager
- A manager may be a top-level manager or report to another manager

And:

- An employee may view/update any records s/he personally created.
- A manager may view/update any records that s/he or anyone who reports
  to him/her created.

So, for instance:

Bob is a top level manager.
Sally and Eric report to Bob.
Henry reports to Sally.
Betty reports to Henry.

If Betty creates a record, it should be accessible by Betty, Henry, Sally and Bob (but not Eric).
However, if Sally creates a record, it should only be accessible by Sally and Bob.

First, is this possible without creating an entirely custom authorization module, using just Django or existing Django extensions?

Secondly, if it is possible, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need any special module for doing that. Benefits of using Django are more related to its object-mapped-entity, that makes more easier managing database entitie and its relationships. So, for your case, you could start to define the data model.

That said, there are some common modules like **[django rules](https://github.com/maraujop/django-rules)** that implement some of the features you need and can accelerate your development.